# How to know when a coherence cache is finished with initial replication?

Tags: oracle-coherence

I have some startup logic for my coherence node; however, I want to wait for a specific cache to finish replicating before executing my logic.

Is there an easy way for me to know when a cache is done with the initial replication?

We are using "coherence-12.1.2.0.1.jar"

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are various JMX properties that tell you when e.g. the cluster has made sufficient numbers of backup copies. The documentation is: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/manage/appendix_mbean.htm. For example, look for "StatusHA" in that documentation. Here is an article on this topic from one of the product engineers: http://coherencedownunder.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/making-your-cluster-site-or-rack-safe-with-coherence-3-7-1/